# I want to know something about Heisenberg uncertainty principle

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Please correct me if I am wrong. First consider two assumptions and to be very clear, everything mentioned below are just hypothetical scenerios.

First lets say humanity has moved much ahead in terms of science and technology. Secondly Heisenberg uncertainty principle can never be disproved and it is true no matter what. Now lets say in a laboratory some scientists find out the position of electron with 100% accuracy and another is that they are trying every thing possible to find its exact velocity using advance instruments of the future(lets say) and lets say they succeed and also verify this using some type of detector. But since the Heisenberg uncertainty principle is the ultimate truth then there should be some uncertainty in either of the position or momentum. Now we know the position, (so Δx is zero) and to keep the principle true, it is only momentum we are left with that should be infinite to make the product finite. v is accurate but in order to make Δp infinite is only mass we are left with. So will the mass in the equation become infinite in order to satisfy the principle, creating a region of infinite mass(energy). Like creating a black hole or something.

Comment: Measuring a location with absolute precision is impossible, for a starter.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is: if you repeat the *exact same* experiment with the *exact same* initial conditions, you will (in all probabilities) get a different value of $x$ and a different value of $p$.  Thus, after compiling the results of all your experiments, you will still have $\Delta x\Delta p\ge \frac{1}{2}\hbar$.  y

Basically you do not have $\Delta x=0$ so your premise is false.  Quantum mechanics states that you have a *distribution* of positions and momenta, so if you do *exactly* the same thing twice you don't get the same result.  This is unrelated to the precision of the measuring apparatus.

To put this another way: suppose $\langle x\rangle=x_0$ and $\langle p\rangle=p_0$.  By some clever experimental trick you manage to find, from one experimental run to the next (done with the *exact same* initial conditions), that your measured values of $x$ are closely clustered around $x_0$.  Then you would find that your sequence of values of $p$ are widely spread around $p_0$.  Of course, a single run produces a unique pair $(x,p)$ with experimental error bars, but what is the meaning of $p$ if from one run to the next its value changes greatly around $p_0$?  It is in this sense that $\Delta x\Delta p$ has a minimum value.  The spreads of $x$ and $p$ do not refer to experimental error bars but to the uncertainly related to the distribution of $x$ and $p$ even if the initial conditions are identical from one run to the next.

Answer (score 2):

In non-relativistic quantum mechanics the mass of a particle such as an electron is fixed and the velocity is, by definition, $p/m$. So then Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle asserts both that $\Delta x \Delta p \ge \hbar/2$ and also (by implication) that $\Delta x \Delta v \ge \hbar / (2m)$. If you wish to allow for a variable $m$ in the description then you have to go towards the full Standard Model or even beyond it! And then you have a bunch of subtle notions involving quantum fields which I won't get into.

To answer the question I think it may help to underline something about the Uncertainty Principle. A good way to get some understanding of this is to compare it with the case of finding out the note of musical notes of very short duration. Suppose, for example, we play the note of middle C from the musical scale (that's about 262 Hz). With an electronic signal generator we could arrange for a very pure note to be played: a frequency precisely 262 Hz going on for a long time. But now suppose we arrange for the note to be played for a very short time. So short that not even one whole cycle of oscillation is completed. In this case who is to say what the frequency is? If the pressure does not oscillate up and down, not even completing a single period, then it has not got a frequency. More precisely, what is found is that such a short note can be considered to be the result of a whole bunch of notes of different frequencies all sounded together.

So you see in my musical example there is a trade-off between how long the note is sounded---its duration $\Delta t$---and how well-defined the frequency is, which can be expressed as a frequency-width $\Delta f$. And in this example we have
$$
\Delta t \Delta f \ge 1.
$$

Mathematically there is an *exact correspondence* between this result for musical notes and the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle for position and momentum. The Uncertainty Principle is saying that a state of well-defined position *is* and cannot avoid being, a state consisting of a wide range of momentum (just as a very short sound cannot avoid having a wide frequency content). Those futuristic experimentalists mentioned in the question have managed to place an electron in a state of very well-defined position. In so doing they placed that electron in a state of very ill-defined momentum. And this means that no matter how cleverly they subsequently try to find out either the momentum or the velocity, they cannot avoid the fact that a wide range of values may be found.

If, in one attempt, one particular velocity is found, then the trouble is that this is the velocity only *after* the particle interacted with their measuring apparatus. But this offers no guarantee that that velocity was the unique value *before* the particle interacted with the measuring apparatus. A perfect measuring apparatus simply selects among the velocities that are present in the state before it is measured, and reports one such value.

Comment: I especially like your musical note analogy, I had not heard that one before. -NN